# How to highlight a list item when a notification arrives

Tags: android, listview, push-notification, highlighting

I am creating a project in which I want to highlight a list item background when a notification arrives. I have done a thing in it but nothing is working perfectly.I am briefing my case:

Case 1: In first I have done that I have saved order id in shared preference based on notification and run loop to check that list contains that id and highlight that background but sometimes it is creating problem. Can anyone suggest me any other option.

Comment: Add a boolean in your model class and set it true when notification received..and in adapter check if its true..set the background..if not and then dont set the background.

Comment: I have 2 tab : new and pending. I want to highlight items on new card when notification arrives what if  I am on pending tab and a new notification came on new tab

Comment: Then update new tab list...when new tab is clicked...new tab list will get refresh..

Answer (score 0):

In the onMessageReceived() i.e. when notification came from the server. Simply pass the Intent with extras, In the onResume() of the activity get the extras of the intent. Update adapter according to the extras. Finally simply call the notifyDatasetchange().

Comment: but it can be bulk of items coming through notification